# adding a counter in an android activity

Tags: java, android, click

I am very new to `android`. I have a counter on some `SomeActivity`, but when I get to the page corresponding to `SomeActivity`, my app crashes :

```
final TextView counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.laws_counter);
ImageView handDown = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.handViewDown);
counter.setText("" + 0);
```

I want that on click of the `handown`, the counter is idented by `-1`. Here's

```
handDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(NewsActivity.this,
                        "The favorite list would appear on clicking this icon",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                setDown();
            }

            private void setDown() {
                String count = counter.getText().toString();
                int now_count = Integer.parseInt(count) +1;
                counter.setText(String.valueOf(now_count));
            }


        });
```

Is this code correct ?

Update : here's the `logcat`

```
10-22 00:18:05.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.donnfelker.android.bootstrap/com.donnfelker.android.bootstrap.ui.NewsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.donnfelker.android.bootstrap.ui.NewsActivity.onCreate(NewsActivity.java:41)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
        ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post your logcat from the crash. This code is from two differnt `Activities`?

Comment: What's at line 41 of `NewsActivity`? Something there is `null`. Is `counter` and `handViewDown` id's of `View`s in the xml you inflate with `setContentView()` in that `Activity`?

Comment: @codeMagic the 41 line is `counter.setText(Integer.toString(0));`, how can it be null ?

Comment: `counter` is not an `id` of a `View` in your `layout` file for that `Activity`. You can't access `View`s from other `Activity` layout files that way

Comment: @codeMagic Oh sorry, I missed the `textview` in my view !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways that you can implement that functionality but think this would be an easy solution.

Make a helper method:

```
public class PreferencesData {

public static void saveInt(Context context, String key, int value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    sharedPrefs.edit().putInt(key, value).commit();
}

public static int getInt(Context context, String key, int defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return sharedPrefs.getInt(key, defaultValue);
}
}
```

Then simply call the putInt method to save the counter in any Activity and getInt to get it again in any other Activity. As long as you use the same key both places.